# raspberry pi : Auto run GUI on boot

Tags: python, user-interface, terminal, raspberry-pi

I want to run a python script which executes a  GUI on startup(as pi boots up). But I don't see any GUI on screen but when I open terminal my program executes automatically and GUI appears. Also, my program requires an internet connection on execution but pi connects to wifi later and my script executes first and ends with not connecting to the internet.

Is there any way my python script executes after pi boots up properly and pi connected with internet

Comment: you can't run GUI if you are not login. After login Linux runs script `~/.bashrc`

Comment: my pi boots to Pi Desktop GUI automatically. I disabled the login and password as well.I added my link to file in .bashrc file.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing you Pi setup it's a bit difficult. But with the assumption you're running raspbian with its default "desktop" mode:

1. Open a terminal on your Pi, either by `ssh`ing to it or connecting a monitor/keyboard.
2. First we need to allow you to login automatically, so `sudo nano /etc/inittab` to open the inittab for editing.
3. Find the line `1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1` and change it to `#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1`
4. Under that line, add `1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1`. Type Ctrl+O and then Ctrl+X to save and exit
5. Next, we can edit the rc.local. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
6. Add a line `su -l pi -c startx` (replacing `pi` with the username you want to launch as) above the `exit 0` line. This will launch X on startup, which allows other applications to use graphical interfaces.
7. Add the command you'd like to run below the previous line (e.g `python /path/to/mycoolscript.py &`), but still above the `exit 0` line.
   **Note the `&` included here**. This "forks" the process, allowing other commands to run even if your script hasn't exited yet. Ctrl+O and Ctrl+X again to save and exit.

Now when you power on your Pi, it'll automatically log in, start X, and then launch the python script you've written!

> Also, my program requires an internet connection on execution but pi connects to wifi later and my script executes first and ends with not connecting to the internet.

This should be solved in the script itself. Create a simple `while` loop that checks for internet access, waits, and repeats until the wifi connects.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps on Raspian:

1. Make sure you boot into GUI (can setup via sudo `raspi-config`)
2. Edit `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and add your python script to the path: e.g. `@python /home/pi/your_script.py`

It depends on the version of raspian if the path is

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

or

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

I recommend trying one at a time.
(Older version might use this path `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` ([ref](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)))

This should run the script after the UI initialises but you don't have any guarantee WiFi is connected though. I recommend ammending your python script to check if it's connected first and if not retry after a few seconds until it is, then execute the rest as expected.

Comment: it works with some changes. I see only GUI there, No python script and console. Also, script running on boot does not show images